# Create normal along edge length

Tags: python, bmesh

Using the `bmesh` module, I have an edge extracted from other bmesh ops. I'm trying to use the [distance_point_to_plane](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane) utility to find the distance from another point, parallel to this edge to an infinite plane residing on one of it's verts.
The only data I have is the 2 verts of this edge. I'm Using one of the `vert.co` for `plane_co` but I'm struggling to understand how to create the `plane_no` normal.

The normal of the plane needs to face **along** the length of the edge, same as the Y axis is facing in this image:
[image]

The `plane_co` would be the vert on the right.

How do I determine the normal along the length of the edge to use as `plane_no` given only the 2 `vert.co` vectors?

Comment: Can you provide us with a simple drawing of what you are actually trying to do? This is quite confusing. Are you trying to create a plane at one of the two vertices that has its normal facing in the direction of the edge?

Comment: @JiříHonzák I'm not creating anything, I'm simply trying to figure out what the normal vector should be when using https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane

Comment: I want the `plane_no` variable when using https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane to align with the edge along it's length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve. To get a directional vector from two position vectors you simply subtract them.

Let's say you have a point A (3,4,0) and point B (-5,2,1).

Now you want you directional vector to start from A and go to point B.

The directional vector AB-> is (-5,2,1) - (3,4,0) = (-8, -2, 1)

This will create a normal vector that goes along the curve. If you have a plane at one of the two edge vertices, it's always gonna be perpendicula to the edge

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was doing but wasn't sure it was right. I'm getting strange results sometimes. Must be a problem elsewhere